# Extract Text After <hr> tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have a script which extracts data from a page. I can scrape most of it but there is a bit of text that occurs after a "hr" tag; which I'm not sure how to scrape. The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div itemprop="articleBody" class="article-body">
            <p itemprop="immediateRelease" class="immediateRelease">IMMEDIATE RELEASE</p>
            <h1 itemprop="headline">HEADLINE</h1>
            <div class="hidden-lg meta">
                <ul>
                    <li><time pubdate="" datetime="Jan. 23, 2019">Jan. 23, 2019</time></li>
                    <li>News Release</li>

                    <li>Release No: NR-014-19</li>

                </ul>
            </div>

                <hr>

Text Text Text <br>
<br>
Text Text Text <br>
<br>
Text Text Text.<br>
<br>
Text Text Text  <a href="mailto: Text Text Text " class="ApplyClass"> Text Text Text </a>.<br>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>E Text Text Text </p>

            </div>
```

How do I extract the text after the hr tag until the end of the div tag? For the other elements I used something like:

```
    for meta in soup.find_all('div',class_='hidden-lg meta'):
    data = meta.text.splitlines()

    d['date'] = data[2]
    d['type'] = data[3]
    d['release'] = data[4]
```

Comment: hr tag? are you sure?

Comment: Yup. Here's the actual page: https://dod.defense.gov/News/News-Releases/News-Release-View/Article/605068/readout-of-deputy-secretary-bob-works-visit-to-the-united-kingdom/

Comment: It does its right after the ul tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky and seems like a workaround but you can use the `next_sibling` attribute of bs4 element and test the `type`. But it works:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4
import requests
import json
from selenium import webdriver

html = """<div itemprop="articleBody" class="article-body">
            <p itemprop="immediateRelease" class="immediateRelease">IMMEDIATE RELEASE</p>
            <h1 itemprop="headline">HEADLINE</h1>
            <div class="hidden-lg meta">
                <ul>
                    <li><time pubdate="" datetime="Jan. 23, 2019">Jan. 23, 2019</time></li>
                    <li>News Release</li>

                    <li>Release No: NR-014-19</li>

                </ul>
            </div>

                <hr>

Text Text Text <br>
<br>
Text Text Text <br>
<br>
Text Text Text.<br>
<br>
Text Text Text  <a href="mailto: Text Text Text " class="ApplyClass"> Text Text Text </a>.<br>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>E Text Text Text </p>

            </div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div')
text =  ''
el = div.find('hr')
while(el):
    el = el.next_sibling
    if isinstance(el, bs4.element.Tag):
        text += el.get_text()
    elif isinstance(el, bs4.element.NavigableString):
        text += el

print(text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Text Text Text 

Text Text Text 

Text Text Text.

Text Text Text   Text Text Text .
 
E Text Text Text
```